# C++ Car program

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <iomanip>;
#include <string>;
using namespace std;

//here are the functions.  the names are the same as below to make it easier for me and you to read but 
// i fully understand that they do not have to be the same names do to the scopes of the variables

    class car
    {
        public:
        int current;


        void get_Accelerate (int, int);
        int accelerate() {return current;};
        void get_Brake (int, int);
        int brake() {return current;};
        void get_Cruise (int, int);
        int cruise() {return current;};


    };

    double updateIntervalFeetTraveled(double previousSpeed, double currentSpeed) {
         int timeInterval =1;
         double averageSpeed = (previousSpeed + currentSpeed)/2;
         double averageSpeed_FeetPerSecond = averageSpeed * 5280.0/3600.0;
         double intervalFeetTraveled = averageSpeed_FeetPerSecond * timeInterval;


        return intervalFeetTraveled;
    }
    void car::get_Accelerate (int previousSpeed, int speed) {
        if((previousSpeed + speed) > 125){
            current = 125;
        }else{

         current = previousSpeed + speed;
        }


    }
    void car::get_Cruise (int previousSpeed, int speed) {

        current = previousSpeed;

    }
    void car::get_Brake (int previousSpeed, int speed) {
    if((previousSpeed - speed) >=0){
         current = previousSpeed - speed;
    }
    else{
        current = 0;
    }


    }
        int previousSpeed =0;
        int currentSpeed=0;
        int speedInt=0;
        double intevalFeet=0;
        double totalFeet =0;
        string function, currentState, command;
        car car1;
void demoFunction(string x, int speedInt){      



        if(x.compare("a") == 0) {
            car1.get_Accelerate(previousSpeed, speedInt);
            currentSpeed = car1.accelerate();
            intevalFeet = updateIntervalFeetTraveled(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
            totalFeet = totalFeet + intevalFeet;
            function="accelerate";
            if(currentSpeed>previousSpeed){
                    currentState = "Accelerating";
                }else if (currentSpeed == 0){
                    currentState="Stopped";
                }else if(currentSpeed == previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Cruising";
                }else if(currentSpeed<previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Braking";
                }
            previousSpeed = currentSpeed;
        }else if(x.compare( "c") == 0){
            car1.get_Cruise(previousSpeed, speedInt);
            currentSpeed = car1.cruise();
            intevalFeet = updateIntervalFeetTraveled(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
            totalFeet = totalFeet + intevalFeet;
            function="cruise";
            if(currentSpeed>previousSpeed){
                    currentState = "Accelerating";
                }else if (currentSpeed == 0){
                    currentState="Stopped";
                }else if(currentSpeed == previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Cruising";
                }else if(currentSpeed<previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Braking";
                }
            previousSpeed = currentSpeed;

        }else if(x.compare("b") == 0) {

            if(currentSpeed>0){
                car1.get_Brake(previousSpeed, speedInt);
                currentSpeed = car1.brake();
                intevalFeet = updateIntervalFeetTraveled(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
                totalFeet = totalFeet + intevalFeet;
                function="brake";
                if(currentSpeed>previousSpeed){
                    currentState = "Accelerating";
                }else if (currentSpeed == 0){
                    currentState="Stopped";
                }else if(currentSpeed == previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Cruising";
                }else if(currentSpeed<previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Braking";
                }
                previousSpeed=currentSpeed;
            }else{
                car1.get_Cruise(previousSpeed, speedInt);
                currentSpeed = car1.cruise();
                intevalFeet = updateIntervalFeetTraveled(previousSpeed, currentSpeed);
                totalFeet = totalFeet + intevalFeet;
                function="brake";
                if(currentSpeed>previousSpeed){
                    currentState = "Accelerating";
                }else if (currentSpeed == 0){
                    currentState="Stopped";
                }else if(currentSpeed == previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Cruising";
                }else if(currentSpeed<previousSpeed){
                    currentState="Braking";
                }
                previousSpeed=currentSpeed;



            }


        }

        if(command != "d"){
        cout<<setw(5)<< "Function"<<setw(15)<<"Current State"<<setw(15)<<"Current Speed"<<setw(15)<<"Interval Distance"<<setw(15)<<"Total feet traveled"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<setw(10)<<function<<setw(15)<<currentState<<setw(15)<<currentSpeed<<setw(15)<<intevalFeet<<setw(15)<<totalFeet<<endl;
}
int main(){

string demo[] = {"c","c","c","a","a","a","a","c","c","c","c","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"};


cout << "2013 Ford Fiesta.  119 hp, 1.4 liter engine.  the fastest car around.....that a 22 year old can afford."<<endl;
cout<<""<<endl;
cout<< fixed<<setprecision(2)<<showpoint;
cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<<endl;

while (true){


cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<< "Enter single-letter command (or 'h' for help): "<<endl;
getline(cin, command);

    if( command == "h") {
        //help command
        cout << "Supported commands: \n"
                << "        a       Accelerate the car\n"
                << "        h       print this help text.\n"
                << "        b       brake the car\n"
                << "        c       Cruise the car\n"
                << "        q       Exit the program\n"
                << "        d       Demo program\n"
                << endl;
    }else if(command =="q"){
        //command to quit the program
        cout<<"Exit.";
        return 0;
    }else if(command == "a"){
        //command to accelerate the car
        cout<<"Enter a positive integer to accelerate by"<<endl;
        cin >> speedInt;
        cin.ignore();
        if(!cin){
            cin.clear();
            cout<<"You have entered a non numeric character"<<endl;
        }else{
            if(speedInt > 0){
                    demoFunction("a", speedInt);
            }else{
                cout<<"you have entered a negative number or a 0.  Please try again"<<endl;
            }

        }
    }else if(command =="b"){
        //command to brake the car
        cout<<"Enter a positive integer to decelerate by"<<endl;
        cin >>speedInt;
        cin.ignore();
        if(!cin){
            cin.clear();
            cout<<"You have entered a non numeric characer"<<endl;
        }else{
            if(speedInt > 0){
                if(speedInt <=currentSpeed){
                    demoFunction("b", speedInt);
                }else{
                    speedInt = currentSpeed;
                    demoFunction("b", speedInt);
                }
            }else{
                cout<<"you have entered a negative number or a 0.  Please try again"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }else if(command =="c"){
        //command to cruise the car
        demoFunction("c", 0);


    }else if(command == "d"){
        cout<<setw(10)<< "Function"<<setw(15)<<"Current State"<<setw(15)<<"Current Speed"<<setw(15)<<"Interval Distance"<<setw(15)<<"Total feet traveled"<<endl;


            int size_of_Demo = sizeof( demo ) / sizeof( demo[ 0 ] );
            for(int i=0; i<size_of_Demo;i++){
            string x = demo[i];
            demoFunction(x,5);


            }


    }else{

        cout<<"That is not a proper input command, please try again.  press 'h' for help"<<endl;

    }

}
return 0;
```

}

I  have to take what i have done so far and make and accelerate/brake/cruise function. I need to do this so i can make a demo command that will call these functions a predetermined amount of time. I will ad a "d" command to run the demo. I am not sure exactly how to create functions i can call instead of manually just typing it out like i did for the input options of 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

You guys have helped a lot.  this is what i have now and is working.  The only problem i have left is how to make the program not crash if a non numeric number is entered for speed.  i have tried to get a try catch working but i have yet to figure out completely how to do that properly.

Here is the final answer to the question.  Thanks for the help.  i would appreciate it if someone could bump the question back up to 0.

Comment: Select the code part you want to make a function, right click to get your (decent) IDE's source refactoring tool, choose 'make function' and you're done.

Comment: You did it for `updateIntervalFeetTraveled()`

Comment: Think what should go in and what should go out. You have a working (I assume) example of a function with updateIntervalFeetTraveled().

Comment: your right i did.  but for these functions i don't want to take in parameters since it is per-written what will happen.  can i write a function with the parameters blank?

Comment: @user2471571 If you don't need parameters, you don't; if you have to pass parameters along, you'll need them ... What's the problem?

Comment: can a function return multiple things? i will need it to affect 4 different variables

Comment: Look into reference parameters.

Comment: i just updated my code so there are less things required to happen when each button is pressed.  i still need to figure out how to make turn(in command a for acceleration) currentSpeed = PreviousSpeed +5 into a function that i can call so when i build a demo command i can choose how many times to run it

Comment: i have updated my code again.  what i need to do now is in the demo i need to call the functions multiple times and output onto the screen updates for the car for each event

Answer (score 2):

Suggest creating a Car class with attributes currentSpeed, previousSpeed, etc.  Add the functions you need to this class, like accelerate(double amt), brake(double amt), etc.  You have already written these functions.  Then

```
main()
{
    Car car;  // creates a stopped car
...
while (true)
{
    ...
    if (command == "a") car.accelerate(5);
    else if (command == "b") car.brake(5);
etc. etc.
```

I think this will give you a cleaner and more easily modified solution.

Comment: how would i create the .accelerate?